# How to update records in related data models in Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I’m creating an app with two data models:

1) `Model A` with fields: Id, DATE, STATUS, EMAIL_ADDRESS, CASE_TYPE, CASE_DESCRIPTION.

2) `Model B` with another fields (Id, DATE, ADMIN_EMAIL, CASE_RESOLUTION, and no field called STATUS).

- `Model A` and `Model B` are related ONE-ONE (`A` is the Owner).
- Users fill two forms. First form creates record in `Model A`, and the second one: in `Model B`.
- When saving form number one I’m setting record.STATUS = “NEW” automatically, using event `onBeforeCreate`.

I’d like to update the `STATUS` to `BOSS_ACCEPT` in `Model A` after saving form number two (datasource: `A`: `B` (related)).

What should I do?

Comment: How is your form for model B set up? Is the datasource 'Model_B (create) or is it 'Model_A: Model_B (relation) (create)? If it is the first option how are you setting the relation to Model_A? Because if you set the form for Model_B the second way, it automatically selects your current selected record in Model_A as your relation.

Comment: Thank for the answer. Actually, model B i set in the second way. I've already tried add record.modelA.STATUS = "BOSS_ACCEPT" onBeforeCreate and it didn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Is there any other way to change the STATUS in model A?

Answer (score 1):

There are really two ways to handle updating your related Model A record after creating your Model B record.

**Server Side, which is more secure.**

You would need the following in your OnAfterCreate server event script in Model B:

```
var relatedrecord = app.models.Model_A.getRecord(record.Model_A._key);
relatedrecord.STATUS = "BOSS_ACCEPT";
app.saveRecords([relatedrecord]);
```

And in order to reflect this change on the client, you would need to include a datasource load in your 'Submit' button createItem() call back function. This would look something like this:

```
widget.datasource.createItem(function() {
  app.datasources.Model_A.load();
});
```

**Client Side solution.**

In your Form 2 'Submit' button include the following code:

```
widget.datasource.createItem(function(record) {
  record.Model_A.STATUS = 'BOSS_ACCEPT';
});
```

If this answer helps you please mark it as accepted. Thank you.